# Regex to filter two conditions: one after another one

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have string `example_photo_name1.png` and `example_photo_name2.png`. I want to remove everything after first `.` and everything before last `_`.
The expected output is `name1` and `name2`.

I could remove everything after first `.` by using pattern `(.*)\.[^\.]*$`. However, I do not know how to remove everything before the last `_`.
How can I do this?

Comment: What is the expected output for `boring.png` and for `something_else`, and what about `reversed.this_extension`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use pattern `(?<=_)(?!.+_).+(?=\.)`

Pattern explanation:

`(?<=_)` - positive lookbehind - assert what preceeds is underscore

`(?!.+_)` - negative lookahead - assert what follows does not contain any underscore (so we are sure we are just behind last underscore)

`.+` - match one or more of any characters

`(?=\.)` - assert what follow is dot `.`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qz1C6G/1)

Matched text will be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
const string = 'example_photo_name1.png';
string.replace(/^.*_(.*?)\.[^.]*$/, '$1');
```

If you want the prefix `xxx_` and the suffix `.xxx` to be optional then you can wrap them in non capturing groups and add the proper quantifier:

```
/^(?:.*_)?(.*?)(?:\.[^.]*)?$/
```

This way string like:

```
hello_world => world
world.jpg   => world
```

Answer (score 0):

The `(.*)\.[^\.]*$` pattern of yours (used with `.replace` and `$1`) removes the *last* `.` and the rest of the string.

You can use

```js
text = text.replace(/^.*_|\..*/g, '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V4BEIa/2). *Details*:

- `^.*_` - start of a string, any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then a `_` char
- `|` - or
- `\..*` - a dot and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = ['example_photo_name1.png', 'example_photo_name2.png'];
const re = /^.*_|\..*/g;
for (const text of texts) {
  console.log(text, '=>', text.replace(re, ''))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first match until the last occurrence of `_`, then capture in group 1 all chars other than `_`

Then match till the last dot, and after that till the end of the string excluding matching other dots or underscores.

In the replacement, use capture group 1, denoted as `$1`

```
^.*_([^_]+)\.[^_.]+$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `.*_` Match until the end of the string, and backtrack till the last occurrence of `_`
- `([^_]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ occurrences of any char other than `_`
- `\.[^_.]+` Match `.` and 1+ occurrences other than `.` or `_`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IAW6zD/1)

```js
const regex = /^.*_([^_]+)\.[^_.]+$/;
[
  "example_photo_name1.png",
  "example_photo_name2.png"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(regex, "$1")));
```

To prevent crossing newlines, you can add `\n` to the negated character class.